# CSS layout help - fluid vertically and absolute

Tags: css, css-position, fluid-layout

I have a comment system I want to float to the right of my page, absolute positioning:

I want the box to have a max number of comments, not too bothered about the height as I limit the characters

But I want the comments fields to expand vertically based on text in there:

So, outer shell is 200px wide - then each row is 200px wide, 50px float left div for user pic, 150px float right div for comment (comment div must expand vertically - can't really have min-height as one word answer will be 16px max)

Is this possible? At the moment i'm trying setting min height on comment div with overflow:auto but this simply causes scrollbars which i absolutely don't want if i can help it

Comment: I don't understand where the problem is. The default behavior for a `<div>` is to vertically expand when there's much content inside.

Comment: Set overflow to hidden if you don't want a scrollbar. We're not sure what else your're having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is quite probably (no code provided, I can't confirm) that your absolute positioned div are inside nothing. This cause the div to try to take minimal space, hence the scrollbars.

It's usually happens when you position something in absolute in an element that is already positioned in absolute. Absolute item are taken out of the parent context, so the parent container doesn't take space for what is inside. So an element in absolute with only one element also in absolute will act as if it was empty.

[I've made this little demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h9Dzv/2/)

look what happens when you change this line :

```
.comment {position:relative;border:1px solid yellow;padding:3px; margin;3px;}
```

to this :

```
.comment {position:absolute;border:1px solid yellow;padding:3px; margin;3px;}
```

Bam, scrollbars.